# hook_action_info does not create its VBO list item in view

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-commerce, bulk-operations

I am trying to code my custom action using *views* and *VBO*. 
The my view shows the user a list of *commerce line items*.

Here the code:

```
function nlmcode_action_info() {
  return array(
     'vbo_download_pdf' => array(
     'type' => 'entity',
     'label' => t('Download PDF'),
     'configurable' => FALSE,
     'triggers' => array('any')
   ),
  );
}

function vbo_download_pdf($entity, $context) {
  dpm("Do the magic here.");
}
```

I then can see the bulk operation available in the select field but once I have selected my custom *'Download PDF'* option and added to the view, the item is missing in the VBO drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Permissions to *'Download PDF'* have to be set.